# how to acknowledge original authors in R pkg DESCRIPTION file

Tags: r

I am improving a package (intReg) that is largely based on Venables & Ripley code in polr (MASS library).  Is there any standard good way to acknowledge the authors of the original code (large chunks of which are still in my code)?

Currently I have:

**Author: Ott Toomet [aut, cre], using code in MASS by 
        W. N. Venables and B. D. Ripley**

but is there any more standard formulation?

As a side note: I don't think there are any copyright issues as both packages are GPL >= 2.

Comment: You can make notes under the "Author" section of the documentation of the functions for which you use their code.  Like you could mention that part of the code of function X was taken from function Y in some package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CRAN appears to be less stringent on this issue now that they were, say, a year or two ago.

But the canonical reference for how to give credit is probably the [Hornik, Murdoch and Zeileis paper in the R Journal](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-1/RJournal_2012-1_Hornik~et~al.pdf).

Personally, I prefer a looser style and use both the `Description:` field and the `Author:` field as you have above -- which looks fine to me.

But the gatekeepers may have a different view...